# Reducing debconf prompts in debian stable

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

I deploy a device with several debian `stable` machines in it.  We instruct our customers to keep it up to date with `apt`, though they aren't always the most linux-literate people.  Debian 10.8's point-release came with an update of `grub-pc` with this `debconf` prompt:

[image]

I got a ton of calls to my 24/7 support line from customers who were terrified of this.  They didn't configure the machine and so they didn't know the right answer to the prompt and were worried that a mistake would leave the device unbootable.

To reduce my workload during point-releases, is it possible to choose a suitable option by default, avoiding these prompts?

---

[`man dpkg`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/dpkg/dpkg.1.en.html#OPTIONS) describes:

> ```
>   Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts only. Using them 
>     without fully understanding their effects may break your whole system.
>
>   --force-confold
>       If a conffile has been modified and the version in the package did change, always 
>       keep the old version without prompting, unless the --force-confdef is also  specified,
>       in which case the default action is preferred.
>   --force-confdef
>       If a conffile has been modified and the version in the package did change, always 
>       choose the default action without prompting. If there is no default action it will 
>       stop to ask the user unless  --force-confnew or --force-confold is also been given, 
>       in which case it will use that to decide the final action.
> ```

It looks like `--force-confold` is exactly what I want.  It ensures that the config doesn't change during any stable updates.  It would be a problem on a rolling-release, but I trust that `stable` maintains configuration compatibility.

As a non-expert, another pair of eyes would be helpful.  Is this a suitable solution to the problem I described?  In the case of the `grub-pc` update, would it have selected an appropriate location for `grub-pc` and avoid the user-interaction?

A description of `debconf` in [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/debconf) says:

> debconf by default does not re-ask old configuration questions during upgrade of a package, instead it uses old answers to generate new versions of configuration files, providing seamless upgrade capability.

So it sounds like `grub-pc` added a new option, meaning `--force-confold` would be insufficient. It also sounds like `--force-confold` is the default behaviour anyways.  Perhaps `--force-confdef` should also be added to the config.

If so, I'll add these to `/etc/dpkg/dpkg.conf.d/` (or maybe `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`).

Comment: The standard way of avoiding this is to use the noninteractive debconf frontend, or set the debconf priority higher, but this question is priority high or critical depending on circumstances, and bails out in noninteractive mode, so that wouldn’t work. Were the systems set up by copying an image, or was the installer run on every one of them (for initial setup)? AFAICT the only change which could cause this in Debian 10.8 is that the maintainer script checks for its target’s existence, and asks if it doesn’t exist.

Comment: That is to say, in this case, when GRUB was installed, the installation device wasn’t known as `/dev/nvme0n1`. Does that ring any bells?

Comment: Yes, that does ring a bell.  These were installed from an image, and according to the guy who built the machines, there are some generational differences in the nvme drives.  It looks like I should have run `dpkg-reconfigure` before shipping these machines.  Thanks for the help!